# Why does EmulationStation block GPIO event loop?

Tags: pi-3, python, rpi.gpio, retropie

I am working on a custom startup script for the **Kintaro** **[`super kuma 9000`](https://www.kintaro.co/products/super-kuma-9000)** (link is down ATM) case for my *raspberry pi 3B+*

Here is the minimal example:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time

LED_PIN = 7
POWER_PIN = 5

def led(status):
    if status:
        GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
        GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.LOW)

def power_interrupt(channel):
    if GPIO.input(POWER_PIN) == GPIO.HIGH:
        print("power off\n")
        led(0)
        # os.system('killall emulationstation')
    else:
        print('power on\n')
        led(1)
        # os.system('emulationstation')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    GPIO.setup(LED_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(POWER_PIN, GPIO.IN)

    GPIO.add_event_detect(POWER_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=power_interrupt)

    while True: time.sleep(5)
```

The script works fine as is, but if I uncomment the commands that start/stop **[`EmulationStation`](https://emulationstation.org/index.html)**, the script is no longer responsive to GPIO inputs.

> Why does emulationstation block the GPIO event loop?  And how can I keep it from blocking?

For clarity's sake, here is what the *Kintaro board* looks like:

[image: Kintaro super kuma 9000 front]

[image: Kintaro super kuma 9000 back]

Comment: I'd guess the busy loop makes it unresponsive as you will be using 100% CPU.  Perhaps change while/pass to while/sleep(1).

Comment: @joan Thanks for the reply.  That's what I had originally, but I thought it didn't do anything, so I removed it in place of `pass`.  Unfortunately, the pi is still unresponsive to GPIO inputs, even with `sleep(x)`